# Diagonalization of order 2 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $A\in Gl(n,{\bf R})$ such that $A^2=I$.

So we have eigenvalue $\lambda^2=1$ on ${\bf C}$. This implies $\lambda = \pm 1$.

Here I want to show that $A$ is a diagonalization whose entries are in $\{ 0, \pm 1\}$.

How can we finish the proof ?

Thank you.

Comment: Since $A^2=I$, the geometric and algebraic multiplicities of each eigenvalue are equal. In particular, the Jordan form is a diagonal matrix whose non-zero elements are $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polynomial $x^2-1$ which has two simple roots $\pm1$ annihilates $A$ so the matrix $A$ is diagonalizable.